# Sparql query for RDF and mutilple attribute values

Tags: sparql

hi i want to write a query for :

```
<car name="BMW">

<attribute =speed="">

<value>1.5</value>

</attribute>

<attribute =weight="">

<value>30</value>

</attribute>

</car>
```

i want the output in the format : BMW has speed 1.5 and weight 30. i have converted the above into RDF but i cant get my desired results. any help?
hi my actual data is from XML file , and i converted into RDF:

i created this ontology:

```
    @prefix veh:     <http://www.example.com#> .
    @prefix schema:  <http://schema.org/>

    veh:Car
          rdf:type owl:Class ;
          rdfs:label "Car"@en .
  veh:Attribute
      rdf:type owl:Class ;
      rdfs:comment "Attributes that belongs to Car"@en ;
      rdfs:label "Attribute"@en .

veh:hasAttribute
          rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
          rdfs:domain aml:Car ;
          rdfs:label "has Attribute"@en ;
          rdfs:range veh:Attribute .

    veh:hasValue
          rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
          rdfs:domain veh:Attribute ;
          rdfs:label "has Value"@en ;
          rdfs:range xsd:string .
```

---

So generated my RDF graph based on above mapping and got the following.:

```
veh:Car
  schema:name "BMW" ;
  veh:hasAttribute veh:Attribute ;
  a veh:Car .

veh:Attribute
  schema:name "speed","weight" ;
  a veh:Attribute ;
  veh:hasValue "1.5", "35".
```

---

like what should be the query?
my query is:

```
select  distinct ?name ?value

from <http://localhost.com/worksheets/Phd_Example>

where {
?x a veh:Car.
?x veh:hasAttribute ?z.
?z veh:hasValue ?value.
?z schema:name ?name.
}
```

but the output is not good:

i get

```
speed 1.5
weight 1.5
speed 30
wieght 30
```

why am i getting duplicate values?

i want the result to be:

```
speed 1.5

weight 30
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. For one thing you haven't shown the _actual_ data you're working with - which makes it impossible to tell why your SPARQL query doesn't give back the result you're looking for. Please [edit] your question to make sure it has a [mcve].

Comment: i have updated , hope its clear now. my data is the xml file which i converted into RDF.

Comment: Why do you have a class `veh:Car` as instance of itself? You should use some ID for a specific instance of `veh:Car` and not the class itself. The same holds for `veh:Attribute`.

Comment: You have only one attribute with the identifier `veh:Attribute` which doesn't make sense, as this has then two names `speed` and `weight`. You need an attribute for each of those, e.g. `att1` with name `speed` and `att2` with name `weight`.

Comment: Your RDF should be something like that, omitting the prefixes: `URIofParticularCar a Car. Car a Class. URIofParticularCar hasModel URIofModel. URIofModel label "BMW"`. Then regarding the value of the literals, it is not clear what is their subject: URIofParticularCar or URIofModel. Once this is clarified, you can make triples with objects the values for speed and weight.

Comment: hi i updated with the ontology. Where did i went wrong?

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov  **"I don't think that OWL classes can contain literals, as now would be the case with your veh:Attribute."** There are definitely some oddities (and typos) in this ontology, but I'm not sure what you mean in that comment.  Literals can't be OWL individuals, so they can't be members of classes, but I don't see anywhere that OP is trying to make a literal be an individual. **"the objects of your triples should be always a singe URI or [literal] in general,"**  An RDF triple is a three-tuple (subject,predicate,object);  it only has one object.  Turtle allows the notation...

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov ...`subject predicate object1, object2 .` as shorthand for `subject predicate object1 . subject predicate object2 .` That's not really unusual.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, you are right, it was me not reading carefully the data. It would be long an unnecessary to explain what I meant. I deleted the comment to reduce the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always better if you can provide actual data that we can work with.  The data you've provided doesn't have all the prefixes declared, and I assume that the use of **aml:Vehicle** is a typo and should be **veh:Vehicle**.  Here's data with prefixes.  I've also noted something rather strange in your data: you're using the same IRI for an individual and for a class.  That won't cause an issue with the SPARQL query (since SPARQL just cares about the RDf triples), but it's rather unusual for an OWL ontology, though I think that kind of reuse (called punning) might be legal in this case.  Here's the data:

```
@prefix veh:     <http://www.example.com#> .
@prefix schema:  <http://schema.org/>
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

# Classes and Properties
veh:Car
  rdf:type owl:Class ;
  rdfs:label "Car"@en .

veh:Attribute
  rdf:type owl:Class ;
  rdfs:comment "Attributes that belongs to Car"@en ;
  rdfs:label "Attribute"@en .

veh:hasAttribute
  rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain veh:Car ;
  rdfs:label "has Attribute"@en ;
  rdfs:range veh:Attribute .

veh:hasValue
  rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
  rdfs:domain veh:Attribute ;
  rdfs:label "has Value"@en ;
  rdfs:range xsd:string .

# Individuals 
veh:Car                # same name as class, unusual
  schema:name "BMW" ;
  veh:hasAttribute veh:Attribute ;
  a veh:Car .

veh:Attribute          # same name as class, unusual
  schema:name "speed","weight" ;
  a veh:Attribute ;
  veh:hasValue "1.5", "35".
```

Now, the SPARQL query will be just about the same as the structure of the data.  You noted that you're getting "duplicate" results. Let's take a look at them.

```sql
prefix veh:     <http://www.example.com#>
prefix schema:  <http://schema.org/>

select distinct ?name ?value {
  ?x a veh:Car ;
     veh:hasAttribute ?z .
  ?z veh:hasValue ?value ;
     schema:name ?name .
}
```

```
--------------------
| name     | value |
====================
| "weight" | "35"  |
| "speed"  | "35"  |
| "weight" | "1.5" |
| "speed"  | "1.5" |
--------------------
```

You're not getting "duplicates" so much as you're getting a Cartesian product of the possible values.  You've declared that there's a car, and that the car has an attribute.  Then you said that the attribute has two names ("weight" and "speed"), and that the attribute has two values ("35" and "1.5").  Then you have a query that says:

Find a car with an attribute with a name and a value.

There are two names that you can pick, and two values that you can pick, there are *four* ways to satisfy that query.  That's why you're getting four*distinct* results;  there aren't any "duplicates".  It sounds like you actually want the car to have *two* attributes, each with a single name and value.  So your updated data would look like this:

```
# Individuals 
veh:Car                # same name as class, unusual
  schema:name "BMW" ;
  veh:hasAttribute veh:Attribute1, veh:Attribute2 ;
  a veh:Car .

veh:Attribute1        
  schema:name "speed" ;
  a veh:Attribute ;
  veh:hasValue "1.5" .

veh:Attribute2        
  schema:name "weight" ;
  a veh:Attribute ;
  veh:hasValue "35" .
```

The query can stay the same, and you'll get these results:

```
--------------------
| name     | value |
====================
| "weight" | "35"  |
| "speed"  | "1.5" |
--------------------
```

Comment: Thanks alot one last question
veh:Car  
 why is this unsusual? what should be there

Comment: @omar as I said in the answer,  " I've also noted something rather strange in your data: you're using the same IRI for an individual and for a class. " it's uncommon to use the same iri as a class and an individual.  Eg,if we have a class ex:Person, then ex:Omar and ex:Joshua could be instances of ex:Person, but ex:Person wouldn't be an instance of ex:Person.